# ASP.NET : Adding Restrictions to different webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, roles

I am currently looking for some advise & help to how I can avoid people from accessing pages unless they are (1) Logged in , (2) Have the correct role to visit that page.

So far I have done a Login Page / Registration Page & Some more Pages.
I also have a database linked to these pages that stores the users & their respective role (Currently on registration the user can select to be an admin or a normal user)

Now I would like that if anyone who is not even a user tries to access a Page by changing the URL , the system would block that and re-direct him to an error page, and so-on so forth.

Comment: Is this for Asp.net webforms?

Comment: @NileshThakkar webforms using asp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use authorization rules for a particular page or folder in `web.config`. The below code snippet will only allow access to users with admin role to the `AdminFolder`.

```
<location path="AdminFolder">
system.web>
<authorization>
<allow roles="Admin"/> //Allows users in Admin role
<deny users="*"/> // deny everyone else
</authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```

You can expand as required. There's a very useful blog **[here](http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config)**

Comment: @lzzy but using this can the Roles be obtained from the database? As in how I currently Have it?

Comment: Yes, it's possible but you will have to provide the role provider.. why don't you use the built in role provider? Read [here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/role-based-authorization-cs)

Comment: Woah that's a big guide :D So if I use that, will I also have to change my registration form? As in, will it work differently from allowing guests to input their details in a registration form and saving it on a local db.

Comment: Not really.. The part you're mainly interested in is the `RoleProvider` I suggest you read up on it to get a better understanding