# Restrict access to pages in an ASP.NET VB web forms application based on a user role and location from my SQL database?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, webforms

I am using ASP.NET VB Web forms application.

I have created the user login credentials in my on premises SQL Server database.

I'd like to prevent users from navigating directly to a page without having the proper role/location is this possible?

Something like a page load event I am guessing but where do I store the users authenticated credentials from one page to the next?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [ASP.NET : Adding Restrictions to different webforms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32734625)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, so the way this works in general?

The main page - perhaps one with a menu bar etc? Well, you tend to allow/let everyone into that page.

but, then say you create a role called SalesGroup. And if if you want ONLY those users with SalesGroup to use that page?

then I MUCH suggest you create (add) a new Folder (say sales).

Now you can just create/add as many asp.net pags to that folder. But you ALSO just simply have to add a file called web.config to that folder.

Now, any users - even if not logged on, or even if they are logged on? They can't use or see those pages unless they are a member of the given role. (in our example SalesGroup).

So I would suggest the the first main landing page be allowed to be used by anyone. Or make the main first page the logon page (since everyone has to be able to use such pages).

To secure a group of pages, as noted, we assume that those pages are placed in a folder (that would be a sub folder).

and you simple drop in a web.config file into that same folder, and you would have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>

    <authorization>
            <allow roles="SalesGroup" />
        <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

What is really nice:
If a user tries to load/use/navgate to any page in that folder? If they are NOT logged on, then they will be automatic re-directed to the logon page. And REALLY nice is once they logon, then they will jump to the web page in question. So the ensuring of the logon is 100% automatic, but BETTER is they are asked to logon for secured pages, and after logging on, then they are automatic re-directed to that page they were trying to use.

of course, in some cases, I might write some code.

So for example, I have some pages that I ONLY require that users be logged on, but I can in code test/check for roles. This gives finer ability to control and use Roles.

So, in the page load event, you often see code like this:

```
If Roles.IsUserInRole("Staff") then
   ' this is for staff members - jump to staff page
   response.redirect("~/Staff/StaffInfo.aspx
End if
```

So, you can redirect, show/hide display things based on their roles they have.

But, as noted, without any code, you can at least rest easy at night that any secuired pages as per above can't be used unless the user is logged on, and they have the role(s) that you set in web config.

So, the base pages (say in the root of the site) will not be secured in most cases.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Kallal!